# How to solve Illegal key size or default parameters in AES - 256 || JCE files installed

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to write a code which will do a AES 256 encryption and decryption.I have installed the JCE jars in the security folder under jre/lib. But then also i am getting  Illegal key size or default parameters , I have tried all solution but i can not make it working.Please excuse me if this question is a silly one, i am very new to this cryptography.

I am giving my code

This is my Cipher

```
public  Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws Exception {

      Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", new SunJCE());
      //a random Init. Vector. just for testing
      byte[] iv = listOfDecodedkeys.get(0).getBytes(AbstractSecurity.UTF_ENCODING);
      c.init(mode, generateKey(), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
      return c;
  }
```

This is the key generation method

```
 private   Key generateKey() throws Exception {
      //PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
      //SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
      char[] password = listOfDecodedkeys.get(1).toCharArray();
      byte[] salt = listOfDecodedkeys.get(2).getBytes(AbstractSecurity.UTF_ENCODING);
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
      byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
      return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");

  }
```

This is my encrypter

```
@Override
public String encrypt(String strToDecrypt) throws Exception{
    Cipher c = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
    byte[] encryptedVal = c.doFinal(strToDecrypt.getBytes(AbstractSecurity.UTF_ENCODING));
    return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encryptedVal);
}
```

This is my decrypter

```
 public  String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
      Cipher c = super.getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
      byte[] decodedValue = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encrypted);
      byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);
      return new String(decValue);
  }
```

Now i am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 SecretKeyFactory not available
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.aes.security.AbstractSecurity.generateKey(AbstractSecurity.java:198)
at com.aes.security.AbstractSecurity.getCipher(AbstractSecurity.java:187)
at com.aes.security.SecurityService.encrypt(SecurityService.java:76)
at com.aes.security.SecurityService.main(SecurityService.java:165)
```

If i change the SecretKeyFactory to PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
at com.aes.security.AbstractSecurity.getCipher(AbstractSecurity.java:184)
at com.aes.security.SecurityService.encrypt(SecurityService.java:76)
at com.aes.security.SecurityService.main(SecurityService.java:165)
```

How to solve this

Comment: The code works fine for me, including with PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1. However, 1) Don't specify the provider in Cipher.getInstance() unless you've got a very good reason (you don't). 2) Don't use classes from sun.* or com.*, they are not officially supported. Lots of systems have multiple JREs/JDKs on them, you need to install the Unlimited Crypto Jars in the correct directory. If you say you have, but then get evidence like this that you haven't, go with the evidence.

Comment: @JamesKPolk is it working with 256 ?

Comment: The code you posted uses 256-bit keys, and it works for me, using either PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 or PBKDF2WithHmac512.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks for the reply but then why mine is not working ??

Comment: @JamesKPolk in 1 you have said that dont use the provider in Cipher.getInstance().Can you post the modified code ??

Comment: @JamesKPolk what do you mean by correct  directory ??